# Facebook Graph API - Ads Insights with different Action Values from Post

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using facebook Graph API to retrieve action values from campaigns. But the JSON returned is always different from any values from facebook screen.

**My Request from JavaScript**

```
var d = new FormData();
d.append("access_token", "MY_ADS_INSIGHTS_TOKEN");
d.append("fields", "actions");
d.append("date_preset", "lifetime"); // I want lifetime data

return await (await fetch("https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/" + campaignid + "/insights", {
    method: "post",
    body: d
})).json();
```

and after I access the report insights using the URL:

https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/REPORT_RUN_ID/insights?access_token=MY_ADS_INSIGHTS_TOKEN

**JSON returned after access report task**

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "actions": [
            {
               "action_type": "comment",
               "value": "2"
            },
            {
               "action_type": "like",
               "value": "4"
            },
            {
               "action_type": "photo_view",
               "value": "30"
            },
            {
               "action_type": "post",
               "value": "1"
            },
            {
               "action_type": "link_click",
               "value": "7"
            },
            {
               "action_type": "page_engagement",
               "value": "249"
            },
            {
               "action_type": "post_engagement",
               "value": "245"
            },
            {
               "action_type": "post_reaction",
               "value": "205"
            }
         ],
         "date_start": "2018-07-09",
         "date_stop": "2018-07-15",
         "ad_id": null // removed
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "cursors": {
         "before": "MAZDZD",
         "after": "MAZDZD"
      }
   },
   "__fb_trace_id__": null // removed 
}
```

**Facebook Post Results**
[image]

**I want to know**:

- Why Facebook Graph API return the `post_reaction` as **205** since from facebook view it is **160** or **150**? the value doesn't match anything, happens to action **like** too

**Notes**:

- I'm not using any SDK, but this isn't the problem.
- The Ad has only **ONE** ads group and the group has only **ONE** campaign
- I make the requisition at the same time as I see the post. There are no major interactions in this post, it is old enough that the values do not change.
- I known that Facebook cache anything, but this Ad is from 10, July.
- Ad Campaign Insights reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group/insights/
- I accept answers using SDKs or different programming languages like C#, php or Java as example, I want only know HOW make the right request or what is exactly happening.

Comment: Try also looking at the action_target_id on the ad insights - if there's multiple posts on the page, you may be seeing the attributed likes for posts other than the one you're expecting

Comment: I made a request with action_breakdowns with value `action_target_id,action_type`, but only 2 different id's are returned, one is ID of post and the another is ID of page... but values doesn't match yet, post_engagement is 237 and post_reaction is 205

Comment: I'd say it's very unlikely the numbers on the post itself will match the numbers in ad insights. Basically, they're measuring similar but different things. 
The insights for an ad will show actions on the post which are attributable to that ad (+ other posts, which is why I recommended looking at action_target_id). 
The post shows the actions, regardless of whether they were paid or not, if those are visible to you (e.g. if a user deactivated their account, blocked you, or is in a security lockout, their like will be counted in the ad stats, but won't be visible on the post)

Comment: The Ad can include "likes" from page in their results? You say that post show all actions to a user (if visible), so a Ad show only "paid results"? There is a link/documentation about that metric differences?

Comment: You can post a answer with the last comment